# Flink custom source scheduled for every one hour

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to make a custom source which can run only at specific interval for instance 1 hour polling to http.Is there any way I can use scheduled executor inside the custom source and consume as stream.

Custom source is like below:

```
import scala.io.Source.fromInputStream
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.{RichSourceFunction, SourceFunction}

class HttpSource(url: String) extends RichSourceFunction[String] with LazyLogging {

  private var isRunning = true
  override def cancel(): Unit = isRunning = false

  override def run(ctx: SourceFunction.SourceContext[String]): Unit = {
    httpStream(ctx.collect)
  }

  private def httpStream(rec: String => Unit) = {
    try{
      val request = Http(url)
      val response = request.execute()
      if (response.code != 200) {
        logger.warn("Metadata api response status code{}", response)
        isRunning = false
      }
      else {
        isRunning = true
        request.execute{ inputStream =>
          fromInputStream(inputStream)
            .getLines()
            .takeWhile(_ => isRunning)
            .foreach(rec)
        }
      }
    }
    catch {
      case e: Exception => isRunning = false
    }
  }
}
```

and in my main job I am just using as :

```
val httpSource = env.addSource(new HttpSource(baseUri))
httpSource.broadcast.print()
```

Any suggestions how to use scheduledExecutors ?

Answer (score 0):

A stream job supposes to be running indefinitely and the source as well. I woul not over complicate it using `scheduledExecutors`. You can simply make the source not poll data for some interval.

```
var running = true
override def run(ctx: SourceFunction.SourceContext[String]): Unit = {
    while (running) {
        httpStream(ctx.collect)
        TimeUnit.HOURS.sleep(1)
   }
} 
Override
public def cancel(): Unit = {
        this.running = false
}
```

Comment: How the checkpoint would behave here if I use sleep since I am planning to use broadcast and use it with other stream source where I would map the values from http source with the kafka stream values